# Unable to get mouseClickEvent trigger on PyQtGraph

Tags: python, mouseclick-event, pyqtgraph

I have a script which renders a PyQtGraph. The nodes in the graph should support mouse click events (especially left click) and get the position of the mouse click. I have tried getting it worked but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The following is a snippet from my code.

```
class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)
        self.scatter.sigClicked.connect(self.onclick(pg.GraphItem)) <<<<<<<<<<

    def onclick(self, item):
        items = item.pos(self)
        print("Plots:", [x for x in items if isinstance(x, pg.GraphItem)])

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'w')
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

w = pg.GraphicsWindow()  # creating an instance of the PyQt GraphicsWindow
w.setWindowTitle('H2 tree for Emails')  # set the title of the graphic window
v = w.addViewBox()  # add a view box to the graphic window
v.setAspectLocked()
g = Graph()  # create an instance of the class Graph
v.addItem(g)  # add the created graph instance to the view box

g.setData(pos=positions, adj=adj, size=0.01, pxMode=False, text=text)  # set the node in the graphic window
```

It throws an error at statement marked with arrows with error "TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'".

Can somebody help me with this. I do not intend to make any changes in the graphic rendering code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are connecting the sigClicked signal incorrectly, to the connect function you must pass the name of the function, you should not pass it an item:

```
class Graph(pg.GraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.GraphItem.__init__(self)
        self.scatter.sigClicked.connect(self.onclick) 

    def onclick(self, plot, points):
        for point in points:
            print(point.pos())
```

Comment: Sometimes I just literally do not understand PyQtGraph. Thank you very much, it worked.